# How to make a paragraph with few words in each line?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how do I make the paragraph with only few words in it. Like as you can see in the picture 'WORKING WITH design LAB' is in one line. How do I make it look like :

WORKING WITH
design LAB

[image]
<sub>(source: [part.lt](http://www.part.lt/img/7d1c99a5bdc7988170a6e578b123c506331.PNG))</sub>

Comment: use two paragraphs or use a line break `<br/>`

Comment: use <br/> after 2 words, The text will wrap in next line.

Comment: If you put your page in a https://jsfiddle.net/ we may be able to assist you better.

Comment: @AlexG that simple. LOL. thought it is going to be something with css.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes thank you. Have not heard of this site before.

Comment: Check it out. It is pretty cool. You can add your html page with javascript using lots of framework. Then you can share it with us, so we can edit it, create a new page with a solution and share it with you.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes I will check it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Use that:

```
<p>WORKING WITH<br>design LAB</p>
```

---

> The HTML 
>  Element (or HTML Line Break Element) produces a line break in text (carriage-return). It is useful for writing a poem or an address, where the division of lines is significant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p>Working with <br> design lab</p>
```

or you can wrap your `<p>` in a div and give it a fixed width:

```
<div class="wrapper"><p>Working with design lab</p></div>
```

in your css:

```
.wrapper{
 width: 50px;  //vary this number to get what you need
}
```

Working demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/7de26225a94a

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to get this

1. Add `<br/>` tag into paragraph
2. Make `padding-left` and `padding-right` with specific values to make text break
3. Add hard-coded `width` value

But keep in mind that on mobile it may looks wrong because of hardcoded `br`, `padding`, `width` values, but then you can use `@media-queries`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cd6m7kbo/3/)**

CSS:

```
p {   
    width:150px !important; /* change the value as per your need */       
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to do so, depends on the target you want obtain.

You can go new line with a <br> special character, or specify a narrow width for your paragraph <p width=15>, and so on.